# Delete / Remove NSTextAttachment from UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextattachment

I have a `UITextView` that will have a mixture of images (as `NSTextAttachment`) and character strings. The `UITextView` is NOT selectable, so I can use:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)textAttachment inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

How do I delete the `textAttachment` in the method?

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttr = [[textView attributedText] mutableCopy]; [mutableAttr replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""]; [textView setAttributedText:mutableAttr];`?

Comment: awesome! post this as the solution and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` of `NSMutableAttributedString` to remove the attachement (you got the range as parameter of the `UITextViewDelegate` method):

```
//Retrieve the attributed string
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttr = [[textView attributedText] mutableCopy];
//Remove the attachment
[mutableAttr replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""]; 
//Set the new attributed string
[textView setAttributedText:mutableAttr];
```