# Change the image of a selected NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, image, nsmutableattributedstring

I have this code for creating an Attributed String with an image on a UITextView

> func setImageOnString(imageName: String) {
>
> ```
>     let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
>     let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
>
>     imageAttachment.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "UncheckedImage")
>     imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 14, height: 14)
>
>     let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
>     let myCustomAttribute = [ "MyCustomAttributeName": "some value"]
>
>     fullString.append(image1String)
>     fullString.addAttributes(myCustomAttribute, range: selectedRange)
>     self.attributedText = fullString
>
> }
> ```

But then I can't find a way of changing this image when something happen like a touch. The problem isn't the touch, it is changing the image.

Comment: Use `enumerateAttribute()` looking for `NSAttachmentAttributeName`, and call `replacingOccurrences(of: with:)` to replace it. See there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535726/how-to-detect-if-a-nsattributedstring-contains-a-nstextattachment-and-remove-it (and the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

Add TapGestureRecognizer in your UILable like below code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lblText.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TouchUIViewController.labelPressed))
    self.lblText.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    self.lblText.attributedText = self.attributedString("menulogout_normal")

 }

 func labelPressed() {
  self.lblText.attributedText = self.attributedString("menulogout_pressed")

}
```

And write separate method for creating NSAttributedString -

```
 func attributedString(_ imageName: String) -> NSAttributedString {

    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Start of text")
    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
    fullString.append(image1String)
    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))
    return fullString
}
```